# What is the Electron Flow in a wire with 2 power sources 180 out of phase?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, voltage

> If you took two independent power supplies and set them to a sine with each power 180 degrees out of phase. The powers supplies will share a common line and the load will be equal_____________?

Do electrons flow both directions simultaneously in the common wire? Or what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The key issue is to know the potential difference between the two power sources. In this case we can compute it.

Can you obtain the result?

Answer (score 1):

Even for one A/C power source, the electrons do not "flow".  Electron drift velocity in a wire is exceedingly slow, on the order of 1 meter per hour.  This means that for A/C power, electrons "wiggle" back and forth about a fixed position.

Comment: Minor nitpick:  since the OP doesn't specify a frequency, there is at least the possibility of a very low frequency sinusoidal power supply such that the "wiggle" back and forth isn't actually the case.

Comment: This thought got started thinking about how the energy in 3 phase moves between the wires.

Comment: I could ask the same question with DC.  I am used to seeing a picture with electrons "flowing" through the completed circuit.  Like any common textbook would show.    But what is acutally happing when a condutor (wire) has 2 equal and opposite loads on it.